# My ReturnUrl is duplicating

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, redirect

I have a page that if you don't have the cookie i want it redirects you to the page the cookie is created.  Basically if you didn't tell me you are old enough you gotta redirect to a page and give me your age.  Long story short if i get redirected to this page where i am asking for you age and the end user doesn't decide to give me there age and click on that same page or another page. My code is adding onto the existing string.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        string referrer = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();

            if (Request.Cookies["Age"] == null)
                Response.Redirect("/AgeRestricted/?ReturnUrl=" + referrer);


    }
```

if I call this page to load multiple times my URLS can get really ugly.

```
http://localhost:14028/AgeRestricted/?ReturnUrl=http://localhost:14028/AgeRestricted/?ReturnUrl=http://localhost:14028/
```

it is like it is concatenating onto the existing. Is there a way for me to prevent this?

I basically want to have it so that i only have 1 param in my ReturnUrl QueryString and so that it won't duplicated if that already has a value.

Comment: Can't you just check if the part is already in the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that fixed the problem. Don't know why my last answer was deleted.

```
 string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

            if (Request.Cookies["Age"] == null)
                Response.Redirect("/AgeRestricted/?ReturnUrl=" + url);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the `Uri` class to obtain only the parts of the referrer without the query string. For example:

```
if (Request.Cookies["Age"] == null)
{
    string referrer = Request.UrlReferrer.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
    Response.Redirect(referrer);
}
```

For more information on `GetLeftPath`, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.getleftpart.aspx

Comment: I really thought this was right after after some testing. This is grabbing the URL before the redirect. So if i am on the homepage and i click on a page that is age restricted. The redirect occurs and this grabs the url of the home page. not the age restricted page that caused the redirect.